# Replace one substring to another string in shell script

Tags: string, shell, replace, sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
filename="test.txt"
firstString="Suzi" 
secondString="I love Sara  & Marry"
 # do something...

#The result must be like this:
resultString=I love Sara  & Marry
```

- what to do if it contains & in string and i am using this command
  but it replace & with suzi like i love sara suzi marry

  sed -i "s|${firstString}|${secondString}|g" $filename

ng="I love Sara & Marry"

Comment: `what to do if it` see and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: secondString and resultString are already the same. Did you want to put "Suzi" in there somewhere?

Comment: no, i want my final result like "i love sara & Marry"
@glennjackman

Comment: I've voted to close the question for lack of clarity. `resultString=$secondString` seems to answer the question, but it's clearly not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp=$(printf '%s\n' "$secondString" | sed -e 's/[/&]/\&/g')

sed -i "s|$firstString|$temp|g" $filename

use above commands to search and replace a string in a file, It worked for me.